# Runtime Error Cannot read property 'element' of undefined in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I have created  form builder  validators that do a validation perfectly but  i need get a error message  from validators so i have tried some method that i shown below

```
 import { Injectable,Output,Component} from '@angular/core';
 import { FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
 import{Sharedata} from '../providers/sharedata';

 export class NextPayDayValidator1 {

    public error: any="Next Pay Date should be greater than todays date";

        constructor(public Share:Sharedata){

        }

 public isValid(control: FormControl): any {
    //  console.log("false");    
      let formGroup = control.parent;      
      var IsValid=true;  
      var errormessage;      
     //  this.Err="eerere";
    if(formGroup) {
           console.log("true");
            var SelVal_Howpaid=formGroup.get('Frequency').value;
            console.log(SelVal_Howpaid);
            var today = new Date();
            var today_date = today.getDate();
            var today_month = today.getMonth();
            var today_year = today.getFullYear();
            var weekNo = 0;
            for (var index = week[0]; index <= week[1]; index++) {
                weekNo++;
            }
            var nextpaydaycontrol=formGroup.get('NextPayDate');
            var date_next = new Date( formGroup.get('NextPayDate').value);
            var date_nextpaydate = date_next.getDate();
            var month_nextpaydate = date_next.getMonth();
            var year_nextpaydate = date_next.getFullYear();
            console.log("nextpaydaycontrol"+date_next +"date"+date_nextpaydate+"month"+month_nextpaydate+"year"+year_nextpaydate);
                 if (nextpaydaycontrol.value == "") {
                        IsValid = false;
                        errormessage = "* Please select Next Pay Date";
                        console.log(errormessage);
                      this.error=errormessage;
                      alert(this.error);
                                        return{
                                                  " * Please select Next Pay Date":true           
                                           }
                    }
            }
    }
```

my addleads.html

```
<ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Next Pay Date:</ion-label>
                        <!--<ion-input formControlName="NextPayDate" type="number"></ion-input>-->
                        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="NextPayDate" (ionChange)="npay()"></ion-datetime>
                    </ion-item>

                    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.valid  && (!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.dirty || submitAttempt)">ddd </span>
                    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.valid  &&  RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.hasError('Paymustgreaterthentodaydate') && (!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.dirty || submitAttempt)"> * Next Payday Must Be Greater Than Today's Date </span>
                    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.valid && RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.hasError('Invalid') && (!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.dirty || submitAttempt)"> * Invalid Next Payday</span>
                    <hr/>
```

and my addlead ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Content} from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import{Sharedata} from '../../providers/sharedata';
import {NextPayDayValidator1} from '../../validators/NextPayDate'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
/*
  Generated class for the AddLeads page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'add-leads.html'
})
export class AddLeadsPage {

  RegisterForm3: FormGroup;

 public NextPayDateErrorMsg:any;
  loading: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,platform: Platform,public np:NextPayDayValidator1 ,private datePipe: DatePipe, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public toastCtrl: ToastController,public loginservice :Loginservice,public sharedata:Sharedata,  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
   public http: Http, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
   this.NextPayDateErrorMsg=this.np.error;
   alert(this.NextPayDateErrorMsg)

    this.RegisterForm3 = formBuilder.group({

        LastPayDate: ['', Validators.required],
        NextPayDate:['',np.isValid]//here i invoke my validator

    });


}
}
```

the above code i have create error global variable.if any error occurs assign errormsg to error global variable;if i trying to execute validation validation will fires  error messge  shown in alert after closing alert  me getting a error like

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AddLeadsPage class AddLeadsPage - inline
>   template:427:65 caused by: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined

any one help me to fix this bugs

Comment: now you can see my updated code

Comment: the error says template.. can you show AddLeadsPage.html? are you calling errors object there?

Comment: now you can see my code @suraj

Answer (score 0):

You have set a custom validator `NextPayDayValidator1` as a component instead of a directive. A component cannot be injected like a provider.
Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation) for custom validators.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[next-pay-valid]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NextPayDayValidator1, multi: true}]
})
export class NextPayDayValidator1 implements Validator, OnChanges {..}
```

**Or** create a provider for `NextPayDayValidator1`

```
@Injectable()
export class NextPayDayValidator1 {
 public error: any="Next Pay Date should be greater than todays date";

        constructor(public Share:Sharedata){

        }

 public isValid(control: FormControl): any {
    //  console.log("false");    
      let formGroup = control.parent;      
      var IsValid=true;  
      //....
}
}
```

and inject in your component constructor.

Comment: in my case validation it s not problem

Comment: now  i have removed component  in my code that time also  me getting the same issue

Comment: Sharedata  is provider that i have created for  sharing data if i trying to access  inside NextPayDayValidator1 me getting the same issue cannot set property issue

Comment: have you declared it as provider in app.module.ts?

Comment: ya i have declared provider in app.module